# bind combobox selectedvalue using enum

Tags: c#, winforms

I failed to bind the combobox selectedvalue.

```
 public void InitializePage()
 {          
    cbStatus.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CourseStudentStatus));
 }
```

on my constructor

```
 public EditCourseForm(int status)
 {
     InitializePage();                      
     cbStatus.SelectedText = Enum.GetName(
        typeof(CourseStudentStatus), status).ToString();         
 }
```

I have tried this too. 
`cbStatus.SelectedValue = Status`

but I'm not able to set SelectedValue on the ComboBox.

**Update**
My enum

```
 public enum CourseStudentStatus
{
    Active = 1,
    Completed = 2,
    TempStopped = 3,
    Stopped = 4,
}
```

Comment: what is the error or problem you face?

Comment: if the status i pass in is 3, i would like the cbStatus to select the id = 3, However, it keeps select the first item.

Comment: It should be able to do something like this .. `cbStatus.SelectedValue = Status`. But why it dont .. it show error "Cannot set the SelectedValue in a ListControl with an empty ValueMember."

Comment: maybe you can use something different, like a string array instead of an enum?

Comment: @giddy: i have updated the question with my enum format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem is  resolved.
`cbStatus.SelectedItem = (CourseStudentStatus)status;`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
public EditCourseForm(CourseStudentStatus status)
{
    InitializePage();            

    cbStatus.SelectedItem= status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your InitializePage() function code to this

public void InitializePage()
    {

```
    cbStatus.DataTextField = Enum.GetName(typeof(CourseStudentStatus));

    cbStatus.DataValueField = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CourseStudentStatus));
}
```

**Updated**
Try with this.

```
var itemValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CourseStudentStatus)).Cast<CourseStudentStatus>().ToDictionary(obj => obj.ToString(), obj => obj.GetHashCode()).ToList();
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
        comboBox1.DataSource = itemValues;
```

here itemValues is a type of `List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>`

Comment: there is no DataTextField or DataValueField for combobox.